# Безопасность выполнения триггера. PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, триггер

Есть следующая ситуация. Я вызываю UPDATE на какую-либо таблицу у которой присутствуют триггеры BEFORE UPDATE и AFTER UPDATE. В триггере BEFORE UPDATE я в зависимости от ситуации устанавливаю флаг в таблицу-помощник, чтобы потом проверить его AFTER UPDATE и в нём же сбросить. В случае одновременного UPDATE-а от нескольких пользователей возможно ли, что другие пользователи увидят недефолтное состояние флага, вследствие того что вышеописанная последовательность действий другого пользователя не завершена? Насколько я понимаю, это невозможно, так как выполнение одной операции UPDATE - это транзакция, так же включающая в себя выполнение всех необходимых триггеров.

Comment: *выполнение одной операции UPDATE - это транзакция, так же включающая в себя выполнение всех необходимых триггеров.* Угу... вот только с чего бы при этом блокироваться совершенно посторонней таблице? *и в нём же сбросить* А если ошибка? неужели при этом AFTER UPDATE всё равно выполняется?

Comment: @Akina, ну раз триггер выполняется внутри транзакции, значит изменение флага в таблице-помощнике тоже часть транзакции и не должна быть видна другим пользователям? Или нет?

Comment: Зависит от режима транзакции. Может, у тебя грязные чтения разрешены...

Comment: @Akina, если я ничего не путаю, самый низкий уровень изоляции транзакции в postgresql все равно запрещает грязное чтение в отличие от других БД. В любом случае, у меня установлен не он. А что касается того, что может произойти ошибка. В этом случае я ловлю исключения и устанавливаю флаг в начальное состояние.

Comment: @Akina, что на самом деле даже не обязательно, в случае если в каком-либо из триггеров произошла ошибка, откатываются все операции в нем самом и во всех предыдущих триггерах.